# EAAccessoryManager connectedAccessories returns empty array after I change the system's language

Tags: ios

I use the EAAccessoryManager to get MFI accessory, first I use the notification to get the connected message, if there have a MFI accessory connect with my iPhone, will get the notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(_accessoryDidConnect:) name:EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(_accessoryDidDisconnect:) name:EAAccessoryDidDisconnectNotification object:nil];
```

when I use [[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] connectedAccessories], I can get the connected MFI accessory directly:

```
_accessoryList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] connectedAccessories]];
```

but when I go to setting and change my language like Chinese to English, then go back to app and use [[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] connectedAccessories]] to get the MFI accessory, but it return nil. if there any one know why and how to fix it, thank you a lot.